# Label content is not refreshing immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a splash screen in MVVM pattern.Which i show from app.xaml.cs onstartup event and then i show login screen and hide splash screen. On login screen when user click on login button i changed the message of splash view model, show splash screen and hide login screen. After that i call the service to validate user login if every things goes fine then i again change splash view model for message update, show splash and close login form. My problem is when i change splash screen message second time it is not showing on splash screen. Below is my code.

```
 public class SplashViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _strMessage = "Loading";
    public string Message { get { return _strMessage; }
                            set { _strMessage = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); } }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnStartup(e);

        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (s, d) =>
         {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
         };

        ShowSplash();
        ShowLogin();

        //BootStrapper bs = new BootStrapper();
        //bs.Run();
    }

    private void ShowSplash()
    {
        sp = new Splash.Splash();
        spVM = new Splash.SplashViewModel();
        sp.DataContext = spVM;
        sp.Show();
    }

    private void ShowLogin()
    {
        LoginControl.LoginViewModel lgVM = new LoginControl.LoginViewModel();
        lg = new Login();
        lg.DataContext = lgVM;
        lg.LoginNotification += (s) =>
          {
              if (s == Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Success)
              {
                  //sp.Message = "Loading Modules....";
                  //sp.ShowMessage();
                  lg.Close();
                  //sp.Show();                      
                  BootStrapper bs = new BootStrapper();
                  bs.Run();
              }
              else if(s==Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Canceled)
              {
                  lg.Close();
                  sp.Close();
              }
          };
        lg.SplashController += (show, message) =>
          {
              if (show)
              {
                  spVM.Message = message;                 
                  //sp.Message = message;
                  //sp.ShowMessage();
                  sp.Show();
                  //sp.UpdateLayout();
              }
              else
                  sp.Hide();                      

          };

        sp.Hide();
        lg.Show();
    }
```

Login.xaml.cs

```
 public Action<Infrastructure.Enums.Status> LoginNotification { get; set; }

    public Action<bool, string> SplashController { get; set; }
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SplashController.Invoke(true, "Authenticating...");

            txtLoging.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            txtPassword.GetBindingExpression(Infrastructure.AttachedProperty.PasswordAssistent.PasswordValue).UpdateSource();

            bool? a = txtLoging.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty) as bool?;
            bool? b = txtPassword.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty) as bool?;

            if (!a.Value && !b.Value)
            {                    

                Hide();                    
                Service.DBOperationServiceContractClient service = new Service.DBOperationServiceContractClient();
                var parm = new Service.DataContract.DBParametersDataContract()
                {
                    ProcedureName = "AuthenticateUser",
                    Params = new List<Service.Entity.DBParameter>() { new Service.Entity.DBParameter() {ParameterName= "@username", ParameterValue=txtLoging.Text,ParamerterType= DbType.String }
                                                                                ,new Service.Entity.DBParameter() {ParameterName= "@passowrd", ParameterValue=txtPassword.Password,ParamerterType= DbType.String }}                       
                };
                var output = service.DBReadOperation(parm);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
                if (output.ReadValue.Tables.Count > 0 && output.ReadValue.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Todo Keep logged in user details 
                    SplashController.Invoke(true, "Loading Modules....");
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
                    LoginNotification.Invoke(Infrastructure.Enums.Status.Success);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<Service.FaultContract.Fault> ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }          

    }
```

I know i have written code in code behind for login that volute the MVVM rule i will move code to the view model.

Please do let me know how i can show message on splash screen in immediately.

Comment: `throw exc;` Just don't. You are removing the stacktrace from a perfectly well-formed exception. Use just `throw;` if you want to rethrow an exception (although you should ask yourself why you are catching them in the first place).

Comment: Do you start a thread or Task anywhere? Your UI will not update, as long as your code is running in the UI thread. Only after it's done and has given control back will messages be handled and the UI be updated.

Comment: Perfect thanks for you help